# Fruit identification

Tags: botany, species-identification, fruit

On the way from school to home, I came across this strange looking fruit that looks similar to a potato and it grows on a tree. Can you identify it?

[image: image shows a round, brownish fruit with green tendrils]

Comment: Where is this image taken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it looks like medlar. Medlar is a fruit sized about 4cm (1 1/2 inch). it must be common medlar.

[image]

You can find out more about this interesting fruit [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mespilus_germanica) at Wikipedia.

> The medlar was already being cultivated about three thousand years ago in the Caspian Sea region of northern Iran and Azerbaijan. It was introduced to Greece around 700 BC, and to Rome about 200 BC. It was an important fruit plant during Roman and medieval times. By the 17th and 18th centuries, however, it had been superseded by other fruits, and is little cultivated today.

Comment: Looks like that to me too. +1. Don't know exactly why you got a down vote. Don't think this correct answer deserved it. Perhaps because it is heavily link-dependent, and link rot can destroy it? I'll edit the picture in for you.

Comment: first answered "it looks like medlar but dont sure about details i dont even touched before" i was trying to say "i saw multiple times but never look that close" i guess first answer deserved that down vote. edited and added wikipedia image link because of that down vote :) there is also another fruit called japanese medlar or loquat but it is in different genus. and there is a nice coincidence have to tell, yesterday went to grocery for buying some potatoes and saw medlar went back to home and after surfing little bit saw question when just asked. and i hardly remembered what was its name :)